# Why does aptitude give me intel-microcode upgrades when I have an AMD processor?

Tags: aptitude, amd-processor

I have a Supermicro AS-2022G-URF (H8DGU motherboard) with 2 AMD Opteron 6272 16C/16T 2.1GHz and an LSI MegaRAID SAS 2108 RAID controller currently running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (scheduled to be upgraded to 16.04 this summer). Several times over the last year, when I have done aptitude update/upgrade, the intel-microcode package has shown up as one of the packages that will be installed. Since this server has AMD processors, not Intel, Why does aptitude offer this package? Is it in any way necessary for other reasons? Any ill effects from going along with aptitude on this?

Comment: The schedule for upgrading 14.04 should have been sent to **before** its support ended, not several months later. The release was End of Life in April and your question is off-topic for that reason.

Comment: OK. I picked that server because it is a critical one we care about and has the raid card. So, I have another server which is running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. It is a Supermicro AS-2022G-URF (H8DGU motherboard) with 2 AMD Opteron 6344 12C/12T 2.6GHz CPUs, but no LSI card. When I run apt on it, it is currently showing as upgradeable, "intel-microcode/xenial-updates,xenial-security 3.20190514.0ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.20190514.0ubuntu0.16.04.1]". Why?

Comment: Both intel and AMD microcodes are now dependencies of the Linux kernel. Obviously, if you have an AMD CPU, only the matching microcode will be loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it is a dependency of the kernel.
I checked running the command below:

```
$ apt depends linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic
Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic
Depends: linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic
Depends: linux-firmware
Depends: intel-microcode
Depends: amd64-microcode.
Recommends: thermald
```

There should be no harm, they won't load to the wrong cpu.

Comment: The `sudo` is not needed for operations with apt cache, so I removed it for you.