# Why is "Processor microcode for Intel CPU" is installed even though I don't have an Intel CPU?

Tags: intel, cpu, 19.10, amd-processor, microcode

In one of the update prompts I get this

[image: screenshot]

This leaves me wondering, why does Ubuntu install it in the first place if it should be of no use? (my CPU is made by AMD)
Is it just to have it ready whenever I boot the system on a totally different hardware?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica I remember there was a separate package for AMD (which I recently updated too)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147478/why-does-aptitude-give-me-intel-microcode-upgrades-when-i-have-an-amd-processor

Comment: oops yeah I found it's a duplicate, sorry

Comment: You can vote to close as the appropriate dupe. Thanks!