# Ubuntu22.04.1 LTS Software Updater offering Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs when system is using an AMD processor

Tags: 22.04, update-manager, amd-processor, microcode

A recent Software Updater run on a Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system that uses an AMD processor is offering a "Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs"

I noticed this under the Ubuntu Base files to be downloaded and find it odd that an Intel file would be downloaded if my system uses an AMD processor.

Found this link [Why does aptitude give me intel-microcode upgrades when I have an AMD processor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147478/why-does-aptitude-give-me-intel-microcode-upgrades-when-i-have-an-amd-processor) with the answer claiming "a dependency of the kernel" but surely the kernel will not required Intel files to run with the AMD processor.

Why would Ubuntu "Software Updater" offer this update if it is not related to an AMD processor?

Comment: If it has been defined as a dependency then it is a dependency.

Comment: I can understand it being defined as a dependency if I were running on an Intel Processor but why would it be applicable if using an AMD processor? There is the                              Depends: amd64-microcode listed if I run $ apt depends linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic
  Depends: linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic
  Depends: linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-47-generic
  Depends: linux-firmware
  Depends: intel-microcode
  Depends: amd64-microcode
  Recommends: thermald

Comment: Dependencies are dependencies irrespective of some hardware detection happening or not.

Comment: I used Synaptic Package Manager to completely remove the intel-microcode 3.20220809.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 as it is Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs. After complete removal I rerun Software Updater and all software is now up to date and no more nonsense intel-microcode is listed to download and install.

Answer (score 0):

I used Synaptic Package Manager to completely remove the intel-microcode 3.20220809.0ubuntu0.22.04.1 as it is Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs. After complete removal I rerun Software Updater and all software is now up to date and no more nonsense intel-microcode is listed to download and install.

Answer (score 0):

No worries AMD now has [Zenbleed](https://lock.cmpxchg8b.com/zenbleed.html). So we need a microcode firmware for AMD now. See the [binary blob](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amd-ucode/microcode_amd_fam17h.bin?id=69143e8eca62a80b9791b8d358d1cc4c90e373c9) in the Linux kernel repo. Hopefully a new kernel update or AMD package or a BIOS firmware update will fix this vulnerability on Zen2 AMD processors.